# Python Pandas calculating log returns between rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe containing prices indexed by date.  Is there a way to calculate the log return from one day to the next?

So if my original dataframe looks like this:

```
            BBG.XSTO.FABG.S BBG.XETR.BIO3.S BBG.XPAR.BOL.S  BBG.XMCE.AIR.S  
date                
03/02/2014  8.785104        81.151          3.938           51.4627
04/02/2014  8.805004        81.151          4.142           51.4627
05/02/2014  8.866988        82.007          4.197           50.5261
06/02/2014  9.038363        82.135          4.162           51.4134
07/02/2014  8.978838        83.512          4.126           51.7585
```

How can I apply the formula:

```
log(today_price / yesterday_price)
```

so I get something that looks like:

```
            BBG.XSTO.FABG.S BBG.XETR.BIO3.S BBG.XPAR.BOL.S  BBG.XMCE.AIR.S  
date                
03/02/2014  na               na             na              na
04/02/2014  0.002262636      0              0.050505783     0
05/02/2014  0.007014971      0.010492993    0.013191221    -0.018367239
06/02/2014  0.019142907      0.001559626    -0.008374256    0.017408804
07/02/2014  -0.006607599     0.016626099    -0.008687313    0.006689831
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [`shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html#pandas.DataFrame.shift) and [`np.log`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.log.html):

```
In [158]:
np.log(df/df.shift())

Out[158]:
            BBG.XSTO.FABG.S  BBG.XETR.BIO3.S  BBG.XPAR.BOL.S  BBG.XMCE.AIR.S
date                                                                        
2014-03-02              NaN              NaN             NaN             NaN
2014-04-02         0.002263         0.000000        0.050506        0.000000
2014-05-02         0.007015         0.010493        0.013191       -0.018367
2014-06-02         0.019143         0.001560       -0.008374        0.017409
2014-07-02        -0.006608         0.016626       -0.008687        0.006690
```

Comment: Thanks EdChum as always perfect

Answer (score 4):

I think using the built-in operation diff is better to get the same results

`np.log(df).diff()`

I like it a little more because it reads better, it's clearer what you're doing

`np.log(df)`  log, `.diff()` return